# retrieving names(table) following subset where only 1 observation

Tags: r

My issue is that when I try to retrieve `names(myresults)` after subsetting  a table I get null when the returned subset has only 1 result. Rather than returning a character vector of row names r returns an integer (in this case of 1).

Here is a table

```
head(tbl)
               1 2 3 4 5 6
      afford   0 1 0 0 0 0
      app      0 0 0 1 0 0
      back     0 1 0 0 0 0
      cancel   0 0 0 0 1 0
      charg    0 0 0 0 0 1
      download 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I have been subsetting the table within a loop to return a table for each group. If a term belongs to a group it has a value of 1:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(tbl)) {
  t <- tbl[which(tbl[,i]==1),i]
  nam <- names(t)
  df <- as.data.frame(nam)
  names(df) <- paste0("Cluster ",i)
  print(kable(df))
}
```

This loop seems to work OK when there are more than one instance of a term returned by `which()`. But the group 4, which has only 1 term "app" gives me issues. Here's an example on group 3, which works as expected then on group 4, which does not:

```
> t <- tbl[which(tbl[,4]==1),4] # only 1 observation meets this criteria
> t
[1] 1
> t <- tbl[which(tbl[,3]==1),3] # 3 observations meet this criteria
> t
aword    cat    dog 
      1       1       1
```

So I can get `names(t)` for `tbl[,3]` where it has 3 returned instances but not for `tbl[,4]` which only has 1.

```
> t <- fintab[which(fintab[,4]==1),4]
> names(t)
NULL # expected "app"

> t <- fintab[which(fintab[,4]==1),4]
> names(t)
[1] "aword" "cat"    "dog"
```

How can I get names(t) when I have only 1 instance returned like in the example?

Some further context following comment below:

```
> str(tbl)
 'table' int [1:33, 1:6] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:33] "aword" "app" "cat" "dog" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
>
```

and

```
> dput(tbl)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(33L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("aword", "app", "back", "cancel", "charg", "download", 
    "enough", "expens", "get", "great", "just", "like", "love", 
    "cat", "dog", "bla", "month", "much", "need", 
    "never", "phone", "pleas", "blabla", "realli", "term", "sign", 
    "thank", "time", "triangle", "use", "want", "will", "work"), c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

Comment: What is `tbl`?  Is it a `matrix/table/data.frame`?

Comment: HI, for context: tbl <- table(row.names(as.matrix(d)), kfit$cluster), appended str(tbl) to my question

Comment: I would have been if you showed the `dput` of `tbl`

Comment: We can use `drop=FALSE` which will have the names as well `tbl[tbl[,4]==1, 4, drop=FALSE]` i.e. `row.names(tbl[tbl[,4]==1, 4, drop=FALSE])
#[1] "app"`

Answer (score 2):

As we are subsetting a single column, we get the logical index (`tbl[,4] ==1` - no need to wrap with `which` unless there are NAs.  In that case, the `which` remove those NAs) and use that to subset the column vector.

```
tbl[,4][tbl[,4]==1]
#  app 
#  1 

tbl[,3][tbl[,3]==1]
#   cat blabla   time 
#     1      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks but what about drop=FALSE in your comment? I looked up ?which but did not see anything. What does drop=FALSE do, because it worked too

Comment: @DougFir It will ensure that the original dimensions are not dropped.  It is applicable to matrix/data.frame/table etc when there is a single column/single row, it drops to a vector.  More info can be found in `?"["`